# StartActivityForResult is not returning data to parent activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, startactivityforresult

have three Activity A,B,C, in Activity A an intent opens Activity B.On activity B startActivityForResult is called and opens C. but after calling setResult in C it is returning to Activity A not to B 
i am copying my activity code where iam calling start activity create event

```
     @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            alertDialogBox.dismiss();
            Intent image = new Intent(CreateEventActivity.this, CropImageActivity.class);
            image.putExtra("data", data.getData().toString());
            startActivityForResult(image, 2);

        }

    }
    if (requestCode == 2) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String bt = data.getStringExtra("result");
            file_path = data.getStringExtra("filepath");
            testPath = new File(file_path);
            Log.e("desti", testPath.toString());
            Log.e("destpat", testPath.getAbsolutePath());
            try {
                testPath.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(bt, Base64.DEFAULT);
                bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);

                //  imageforUpload = getStringImage(bitmap2);
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                // down sizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
                // images
                options.inSampleSize = 8;

                final Bitmap bitmaptest = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_path, options);

                imgCropped.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imgCropped.setImageBitmap(bitmaptest);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

second activity cropActivity where i am returning data to parent

```
     private final CropCallback mCropCallback = new CropCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Bitmap cropped) {
        int height = cropped.getHeight();
        int width = cropped.getWidth();
        if (height<400||width<400){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"this image cat be cropped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {

            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cropped, 0, 0, 400, 400);


            imgtest.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            SaveImage(bitmap);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
            String temp = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);


            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("result", temp);
            returnIntent.putExtra("filepath", filePath);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

please help me to solve this ,the returning page is another activity

Comment: are you finishing Activity B before after calling Activity C ?

Comment: @sohanshetty no

Comment: please provide the class name, so It will be clear from which class you calling which class

Comment: @JoseAntony When you are starting an activity with StartActivityForResult, from which Activity it came from? because i see you have implemented the code in OnActivityResult

Comment: Make sure you are not calling finish() "before or after" executing startActivityForResult(yourIntent, SELECT_FILE);

Comment: @A.R. i am only calling finish on setResult in second activity

Comment: You mean to say calling finish on ThirdActivity

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have to correct your requestCode

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result", temp);
returnIntent.putExtra("filepath", filePath);
setResult(2, returnIntent);
finish();
```

Because you have mentioned the same here

```
Intent image = new Intent(CreateEventActivity.this, CropImageActivity.class);
image.putExtra("data", data.getData().toString());
startActivityForResult(image, 2);
```

Comment: i have changed the request code but it not working yet

Comment: @JoseAntony Try to debug and make it confirm whether it is coming inside onActivityResult or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
First a fall you need to check the flow of control of your code, whether its going in correct blocks or not.
```

***Alternatively*** you can follow below solution(If you wish), instead of using **startActivityForResult()** you can use **onNewIntent()** as a callback method.

```
You need to follow few steps.
```

**Step 1:** Declare launchMode of your '**CreateEventActivity**' as "**singleTask**" in your AndroidManifest.xml

**Example:**

```
 <activity android:name=".CreateEventActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

**Step 2:** Override *onNewIntent()* in your 'CreateEventActivity'

**Example:**

```
 @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        if(intent!=null)
        {
            // YOU CAN CHECK FLAGS OVER HERE, BY PASSING THE VALUES THROUGH INTENTS from different other activities
             if(intent.getBooleanExtra("IS_COMING_FROM_CROP_ACTIVITY",false)
             {
                // HANDLE YOUR STUFF
             }
        }
    }
```

**Step 3:** How to trigger this callback
    Simply use startActivity(), that is startActivity(B,C) and Once 'Activity C' works done startActivity(C,B) and call finish() on Activity C

**Example**

**From 'CreateEventActivity'**

```
startActivity(new Intent(CreateEventActivity.this, CropImageActivity.class));
```

**From 'CropImageActivity**'

```
startActivity(new Intent(CropImageActivity.this, CreateEventActivity.class));
finish();
```

**Note:** Don't worry Activity B instance won't create again and again. Try this solution if you not been able to find the issue w.r.t startActivityForResult().